# Словосочетание со словом "участвовать"

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис, грамматика, словосочетания

Глагол "участвовать" управляет дополнением в вин. падеже с предлогом "в". Допустимо ли в словосочетаниях употреблять его не с дополнением, а с обстоятельственным местоимённым наречием "где"?

*Участвовать где-то* (а не "в чём-то")

*Нигде не участвовать* (а не "ни в чем")

Answer (score 2):

Вариант "нигде не участвовать" употребляется достаточно часто, в разговорной речи можно услышать вопрос "Участвуешь где-то?", а вот в утвердительной форме глагол "участвовать", насколько мне известно, используется только с дополнением.  Было бы хорошо, если бы Вы привели пример, в котором хотите употребить "где-то".

Comment: В вопросе уже содержится два примера.

Comment: Прошу прощения, я сначала неверно Вас поняла. Тогда все так, как я ответила выше.